# In e-mail from Google Sheets including image for signature takes out formatting of message

Tags: google-sheets, gmail, google-apps-script

Sending emails from Google Sheets I have a compiled text (with line breaks) which is stored in var message. I have been trying to include a picture for the signature. To display it, I used the HTML body in the options parameter (as suggested [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)). This is the code:

```
function sendEmails() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 2);  // Fetch the range of cells B1:B1
var subject = range.getValues();   // Fetch value for subject line from above range
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 9);  // Fetch the range of cells I1:I1
var numRows = range.getValues();   // Fetch value for number of emails from above range
var startRow = 4;                  // First row of data to process
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows,9 ) // Fetch the range of cells A4:I_
var data = dataRange.getValues();  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var googleLogoUrl = "http://die-masterarbeit.de/media/grafik/logo.png";
var googleLogoBlob = UrlFetchApp
                     .fetch(googleLogoUrl)
                     .getBlob()
                     .setName("googleLogoBlob");
for (i in data) {
var row = data[i];
var emailAddress = row[0];      // First column
var message = row[8];           // Ninth column

MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,
             subject,
             message,
{
name: 'Peter Peschel',
htmlBody: "<img src='cid:googleLogo'>",
inlineImages:
  {
    googleLogo: googleLogoBlob,
  }
})};
}
```

What happens is that the message variable is not displayed at all. I have experimented in calling on the message variable in the `htmlbody` again, but this completely takes out the formatting (especially line breaks) of the message.

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,
             subject,
             message,
{
name: 'Peter Peschel',
htmlBody: message + "<img src='cid:googleLogo'>",
inlineImages:
  {
    googleLogo: googleLogoBlob,
  },
})};
}
```

Any suggestions on how to best display the image while keeping the formatting of the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the format `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)` of the [`MailApp.sendEmail`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) method. As the documentation says, if options include htmlBody, it will be used **instead of** the body parameter. This is why your first attempt ignored "message".

Since you need to send an HTML message, its content must be formatted as HTML; in particular, line breaks should be `<br>` instead of the control character `\n`.

Solution: replace `\n` with `<br>` in the message body. Here is an example of a script sending the content of cell A1. It provides plainMessage in case the recipient's email client does not render HTML, and htmlMessage with inline image

```
function sendA1() {
  var plainMessage = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1).getValue();
  var htmlMessage = message.replace(/\n/g, '<br>') + "<img src='cid:googleLogo'>"; 
  MailApp.sendEmail('user@domain.com', 'my subject', plainMessage, { 
    htmlBody: message,
    inlineImages:
      {
        googleLogo: googleLogoBlob 
      }       
  }); 
}
```

By the way, since you are using options extensively, it would make  sense to switch to the format [sendEmail(message)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage) where `message` is an object holding all the parameters. This makes for a more readable code:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to:       'user@domain.com', 
  subject:  'my subject', 
  body:     plainMessage, 
  htmlBody: message,
  inlineImages:
    {
      googleLogo: googleLogoBlob 
    }
});
```