# How to put images as part of email response after Google form submission?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

Is it possible to add a script that allows me to insert an image along with the email body?

So, I saw this code online and implemented it:

```
// @ts-nocheck
function addAutoNumber() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  // Get the last row that has content.
  var LastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  // Set the first Auto Number
  var AutoNumberStart="XFILMS100";  
  
  //---- First run ------------
  
  //Check if the first column is Timestamp
  if (sheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue() == "Timestamp") {
    // insert a column to the left and the text "Auto Number" in the first row
    sheet.insertColumnBefore(1);
    sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue("Unique Entry Code");
    // Fix for (probably) a bug that formats the new column 
    // with the same format of the column used to insert it,
    // in this case the column gets the date format like the Timestamp column.
    // So we set the format to number
    sheet.getRange("A2:A").setNumberFormat(0); 
    // check if there are already form responses and add numbers for them
    if (LastRow>1) {
      for(var ii=2; ii <= LastRow; ii++) {
        sheet.getRange(ii, 1).setValue(AutoNumberStart);
        AutoNumberStart="XFILMS"+ (parseInt(AutoNumberStart.match(/(\d+)/))+1);
      }
    }
  }
  
  // ---- Add new Auto Number ----------
  
  // Check if there is a Number in the AutoNumber column 
  // for the last Form Submission
  if (sheet.getRange(LastRow, 1).isBlank()) {
  // Check if it is the first Form submission and set the AutoNumberStart
    if (LastRow == 2) {
      sheet.getRange(LastRow, 1).setValue(AutoNumberStart);
          // ---- Send a response receipt with the AutoNumber as a reference number
    // Get the email from the column D (4-th column)
    // Change the number "4" to the number of the mail column in your sheet
    var EmailAddress = sheet.getRange(LastRow, 5).getValue();
    // Set the email subject
    var Subject = "Hey, there! Here is your Unique Entry Code to the Giveaway!";
    //Create the message body
    // The "/n" in the message body means a new line
    var Message = 'Hi X-Films Patron! \nHere is your Unique Entry code: ' + ("XFILMS"+ (parseInt(LastAutoNumber.match(/(\d+)/))+1)) + ' \nSchedule another appointment to more chances of winning! Thank you and Good luck!';
    // Send the mail
    MailApp.sendEmail(EmailAddress, Subject, Message);
    } else {
      // Get the Last AutoNumber from the previous row
      var LastAutoNumber = sheet.getRange(LastRow-1, 1).getValue();
      // Set the next AutoNumber
      sheet.getRange(LastRow, 1).setValue("XFILMS"+ (parseInt(LastAutoNumber.match(/(\d+)/))+1));
    }
        // ---- Send a response receipt with the AutoNumber as a reference number
    // Get the email from the column D (4-th column)
    // Change the number "4" to the number of the mail column in your sheet
    var EmailAddress = sheet.getRange(LastRow, 5).getValue();
    // Set the email subject
    var Subject = "Hey, there! Here is your Unique Entry Code to the Giveaway!";
    //Create the message body
    // The "/n" in the message body means a new line
    var Message = 'Hi X-Films Patron! \nHere is your Unique Entry code: ' + ("XFILMS"+ (parseInt(LastAutoNumber.match(/(\d+)/))+1)) + ' \nSchedule another appointment to more chances of winning! Thank you and Good luck!';
    // Send the mail
    MailApp.sendEmail(EmailAddress, Subject, Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Yes it's possible. One way is by using  another version of `MailApp.sendEmail`, the one that is able to set the html body --> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options. Another way is by using GmailApp service instead of MailApp, it has two versions of sendEmail method to set the html body. If you need further help, please make your question more specific and provide more details like what is the source of the image to be included.

Comment: P.S. here is a related question https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/84659/88163